# etcd 3rd pod not getting scheduled on master node due to peers expecting old cert

Tags: kubernetes, etcd3

needed hint to resolve etcd cert issue on two etcd server pods

I have 2(3) etcd server pods and these are reporting for 3rd pod that x.509 cert is valid for `etc.test1.com` and not for `etc.test2.com`

so, my assumption is, issue is etcd server pod 2 & 3 are somehow expecting old cert dns name and not new cert dns name value which is etc.test2.com>

this is causing the 3rd pod to never get accepted as a valid peer and pod never gets scheduled on node.

Any hint how can I reset the two PODS that are expecting old cert  and start expecting new cert?

below is the error from etcd server pods that are running .

```
rafthttp: health check for peer 44ffe8e24fa23c10 could not connect:         x509: certificate is valid for etcd-a.internal.test1.com, etcd-b.internal.test1.com, etcd-c.internal.test1.com, etcd-events-a.internal.test1.com, etcd-events-b.internal.test1.com, etcd-events-c.internal.test1.com, localhost, not etcd-b.internal.test2.com
```

Also, will cluster work on single etcd server pod or does it need to have 3?

Comment: You have created the cluster manually or you are running under a ready cluster provided by the cloud provider ?

Comment: Connect to one controller node and issue the following command: sudo ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl member list \
  --endpoints=https://127.0.0.1:2379 \
  --cacert=/etc/etcd/ca.pem \
  --cert=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem \
  --key=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem

Comment: I created it using kops tool and issue was that DNS records were somehow wrongly updated to wrong IP addresses. So, i switched them to right ones and then ETCDs starting talking to right peers and no TLS cert issue was observed. I also had to start the etcd pod using docker run. so this solved my issue. we can close question.